# Add class to last widget in widget area

Tags: php, css, wordpress, class, widget

Im using the the following PHP to display a number of widgets in my Wordpress theme:

```
<?php
// A sidebar for widgets, just because.
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' ) ) : ?>
    <ul>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' ); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically each widget in the `<ul>` comes out as a list item. I want to be able to add a class to the last list item in the list.

Is it possible for me to do this with wordpress/php?

Comment: Do you need that for CSS reasons?

Comment: hahahah of course he needs it for CSS reasons!

Answer (score 2):

Ended up using this function.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-first-and-last-css-classes-for-sidebar-widgets?replies=1

Answer (score 1):

I once coded that wordpress adds a first and last classname to the first and last widget, you can find [the code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/12615/12615.patch) in [the ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12615).

However per CSS you should be able to address the last item by using the [`:last-child` CSS selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html) (all browsers but not IE 5.5 - IE 8). So probably this already solves your issue.

```
ul > li:last-child {border:1em solid red;}
```

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Yeah especially for me as IE 6 user.

Comment: Your sarcasm aside, ["As of January 2011, estimates of IE8's global market share ranged from 26-33%"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8), and it's the last version to be supported on the still widely-used Windows XP operating system (["as of May 2011, Windows XP is the most widely used operating system for accessing the Internet in the world with a 40.7% market share, having peaked at 76.1% in January 2007"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP)).

Comment: Tomalak: That was no sarcasm. My XP boxe don't go over IE6.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a custom class for first or last widget inner sidebar.

You can using action hook "init"

- get all activate widgets, sidebars
- loop through each widget and change the class names

```
add_action('init', 'ak_add_order_classes_for_widgets' );

function ak_add_order_classes_for_widgets() { 
    global $wp_registered_sidebars, $wp_registered_widgets;

    #Grab the widgets
    $sidebars = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();

    if ( empty( $sidebars ) ) {
        return;
    }

    #Loop through each widget and change the class names
    foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar_id => $widgets ) {
        if ( empty( $widgets ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $number_of_widgets = count( $widgets );

        foreach ( $widgets as $i => $widget_id ) {
            $wp_registered_widgets[$widget_id]['classname'] .= ' ct-widget-order-' . $i;

            # Add first widget class
            if ( 0 == $i ) {
                $wp_registered_widgets[$widget_id]['classname'] .= ' ct-widget-first';
            }

            # Add last widget class
            if ( $number_of_widgets == ( $i + 1 ) ) {
                $wp_registered_widgets[$widget_id]['classname'] .= ' ct-widget-last';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my blog: http://colourstheme.com/2015/03/add-class-to-first-and-last-widget/

Comment: You should include the code from behind that link directly in your answer.